# When to use distance between distributions instead of using median based statistics?

Tags: distributions, anova, inference, kullback-leibler

I have a problem where I have to compare the effect of **X** ( univariate random variable) on distribution of **Y** (univariate random variable) between 2 different cases. **Y** is not following a Normal distribution. I am not sure whether to Mean/ median-based statistics (such as ANOVA) or use a distance between distribution metric (such as KL divergence). [image]

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen the KL divergence used as a test statistic. I think this is because it is not sensitive to the sample size, i.e. if the two distributions are different, then a larger sample size doesn't give a larger statistic than a smaller one. Most statistical tests for the difference between two groups concern their means only. (It is also possible to [test for difference in medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression), just less common.) The reason this is the case, I believe is to do with interpretability. If two samples differ in their distributions, then one is then bound to ask --- in what way? Is the mean different, or the variance, or the skew, etc? Another reason is mathematical niceness. Tests of means are the most straightforward and well known, especially when assuming underlying Normality. It is also easily interpretable. Furthermore, a difference in means implies a difference in distributions anyway.

It is also common to use the non-parametric tests such as [Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) or [Kruskal-Wallis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) to test for differences in groups. These tests actually test for difference in *distributions*. However, they are not very sensitive to departures in other moments such as variance and skew.

Comment: Because OP explicitly says data are not normal (they seem to lie between 0 and 1) and histograms are far from normal, I decided to focus on tests/checks of normality and a Wilcoxon test at the end. But I have no objection to your approach (+1).

Comment: Thanks @Tim for clarifying that KL divergence is never used as test stat. I understand what I need to compare the effect of an increase in **X** on the probability distribution of **Y** across 2 cases. As you can see the probability of higher values of **Y** increases with increasing **X**. Can you point in the right direction?

Comment: It was @TimMak who spoke about KL divergence. // It is difficult to give detailed advice based just the few sentences in your Question. "Compare the effect of increase in $X$ on the probability distribution of $Y$ across 2 cases." doesn't bring a specific model or test to mind. Two cases of what? What connection btw $X$ and $Y?$ // It seems your data are far from normal,.so a nonparametric procedure seems appropriate. Maybe 2-sample Wilcoxon, but don't know enough to be sure. If you think it fits, try it. If not, maybe a fresh question with sufficiently specific info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two samples of sizes 20 and 25,
respectively. Descriptive statistics and boxplots follow:

```
summary(x1); sd(x1); length(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2211  0.3262  0.4296  0.4446  0.5710  0.7330 
[1] 0.1534525  # SD x1
[1] 20         # n for x1
summary(x2); sd(x2); length(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.6565  0.8064  0.9148  0.9348  1.0124  1.2987 
[1] 0.1723941
[1] 25
boxplot(x1,x2, col="skyblue2", notch=T)
```

[image]

Boxplots show slight upward skewness, especially for `x2`. Normal probability plots seem nonlinear.
So the data may not be from normal populations.

The median of the first sample is below the median of the second sample.
The notches in the sides of the boxes in the boxplots above suggest
that the difference in medians is significant.

Boxplots show slight upward skewness. Normal probability plots (especially for `x2`) seem nonlinear.
So the data may not be from normal populations. Samples are a bit
too small for reliable results from a Shapiro-Wilk test of normality, but
neither sample is detected as nonnormal by the test.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(x1); qqline(x1, col="blue")
 qqnorm(x2); qqline(x2, col="blue")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

```
shapiro.test(x1)$p.val
[1] 0.2048991
shapiro.test(x2)$p.val
[1] 0.1861775
```

The departure from normality is probably within the scope of the
robustness of a t test, but we use a nonparametric test instead.
A two-sample
Wilcoxon (rank sum) test finds a highly significant difference in location.

```
 wilcox.test(x1, x2)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x1 and x2
W = 1, p-value = 1.262e-12
alternative hypothesis: 
   true location shift is not equal to 0
```

*Notes:* (1) In practice, you can only say what you find in the data.
It seems clear from the data that these two samples did not come
from the same population.  However, in this case the data were
simulated as shown below, so we know for sure that the two samples
are nonnormal and that they differ. Sample `x2` is from a population shifted to the right (by $0.5$) of
the population from which `x1` was sampled.

```
set.seed(602)
x1 = round(rbeta(20, 5, 6), 4)
x2 = round(rbeta(25, 5, 6) + .5, 4)
```

(2) A Welsh two-sample t test would also have found a significant
difference (in population means). There are no outliers and skewness
is quite slight, so it is not surprising that the t test comparing the two samples gives a
useful result.

```
t.test(x1,x2)$p.val
[1] 7.842386e-13
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for generating simulation to answer the question, it was quite instructive @BruceET. I need to compare the effect of an increase in **X** on the probability distribution of **Y** across 2 cases. As you can see the probability of higher values of **Y** increases with increasing **X**. Can you point in the right direction?